# Copy file into different folder directory name

Tags: c#

I already create code for copy but I don't know how to combine copy code if the filename are not in `jpeg`,`bmp`,`png` or `gif` it will copy to different folder name(`C:\Dump`) but if filename extension exists file will be copy into (`C:\Destionation`).

```
public static void CopyFile( string[] args )
{
    CopyFolder( @"C:\source", @"C:\Destination" );
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static public void ProcessDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles("*.jpg,*.bmp,*.png,*.gif,*.jpeg"))
    {
        //how to combin process directory info with copy folder statement//
    }
}

static public void CopyFolder( string sourceDir, string destFolder )
{
    if (!Directory.Exists( destFolder ))
        Directory.CreateDirectory( destFolder );
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles( sourceDir );
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName( file );
        string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
        File.Copy( file, dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to enumerate all files (`Enumerate("*.*")` then switch destination according to extension `file.Extension.Equals(".jpg")` or - better - simply keep a list of them. A _case insensitive search_ for that extension will give tell you if you have to copy in `dump" or `destination".

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the extension of the files with:

> Path.GetExtension(myFilePath);

For example, you can add in your code:

```
foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName( file );
        string dest = Path.Combine( destFolder, name );
        if(Path.GetExtension(myFilePath) != "jpg" && Path.GetExtension(myFilePath) !=  "bmp" && Path.GetExtension(myFilePath) !=  "png" && Path.GetExtension(myFilePath) !=  "gif" && Path.GetExtension(myFilePath) !=  "jpeg"      ){
        File.Copy( file, dest);
        }
    }
```

You can have a reference in the [Path.GetExtension Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx).

Comment: +1 This would work but Adriano's method in the question comments is a bit simpler and would be how I would choose to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) has a property to get the file [`Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx).

You can enumerate all the files and copy depending on the `Extension`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var extensions = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif" };
    var source = @"C:\Source";
    var destination = @"C:\Destination";
    var dump = @"C:\Dump";

    CopyFolder(source, destination, dump, extensions);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void CopyFolder(
    string source,
    string destination,
    string dump,
    string[] extensionsForDestination
)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destination))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(dump))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dump);
    }

    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(source);
    ProcessDirectory(directory, destination, dump, extensionsForDestination);
}

public static void ProcessDirectory(
    DirectoryInfo directory,
    string destination,
    string dump,
    string[] extensionsForDestination
)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        // Check if extension matches
        if(extensionsForDestination.Contains(file.Extension))
        {
            // Copy file to Destination
            file.CopyTo(destination);
        }
        else
        {
            // Copy file to Dump
            file.CopyTo(dump);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how if directory also not exist for Dump

Comment: Then create it like you are doing for the destination.

Comment: thanks for the information..now i will try for delete source folder after copy all files.